# styled component not covering the entire screen

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I've looked at all the previous questions/answers but none have seemed to work for me.
Im trying to get the background to cover the entire page, however, it does not seem to be working with styled components.

What I want to do is create 3 divs of `height: 100vh` and `width: 100vw` and scroll through them.

Below is the code

```
export const MainContainer = styled.div`

  display: flex;

  flex-direction: column;

  justify-content: center;

  align-items: center;

  border: 0;

  padding: 0;

  margin: 0;

  top: 0;

  left: 0;

  width: 100vw;

  height: 100vh;

  background: ${(props) => props.color};

  overflow: scroll;

`;
```

And this is how im calling it:

```
export const MainPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <MainContainer color="green" />
      <MainContainer color="red" />
      <MainContainer color="blue" />
    </>
   
  );
};
```

I've tried using `position: fixed` and `position: absolute`. And while they do cover the page, I lost to ability to scroll through the divs (they all end up on top of each other)
This is what its looking like when im scrolling through the page. Any help would be really appreciated.
[image: Div1]
[image: Div2]
[image: Div3]

Comment: why not use flexbox, flex:1 covers with 100% and height 100% for the device.  then use 
  flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis to control the flow of content

Comment: that didnt seem to work for me. I had flex: 1, width:100vw, and height: 100vh, but it still didnt cover the edges like in the pics above